# How to setState in react dynamically using map function?

Tags: reactjs, state

I am using the following approach to dynamically update the state using map. However this does not work and the state does not change. Why is this approach invalid and what should be the alternative?

```
    values= ['test1', 'test2','test3'] // The array could contain anything 
    this.setState({
          events: [
            ...events,
            values.map((value) => {
              return {
                title: value,
                start: this.state.start,
                end: this.state.end,
              };
            }),
          ],
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong, but to me it looks like you're only missing a spread operator in front of `values.map(...)`

```
this.setState({
          events: [
            ...events,
            ...values.map((value) => {
              return {
                title: value,
                start: this.state.start,
                end: this.state.end,
              };
            }),
          ],
        });
```

Because `values.map(...)` returns an array, and seeing that you spread `events`, I'm guessing you want the mapped values to be spread as well. If I'm misunderstanding something, please let me know and we can look into it further.

Also, unless you destructured `events` from state earlier (in code you did not paste here), you might want to refer to it as `this.state.events`.

---

**Edit:**

A more detailed explanation about why the spread operator was the solution:

In your `state` the property `events` is an array of objects. So when you change it's value, it must again be an array of objects.

Perhaps the most important details is that `values.map` **returns an array**.

`events` is an **array** of objects. The same is true for `values.map`.

So `[events, values.map]` would be an array with two arrays, one in positions 0 and the other in position 1.

But you want an array of objects, not an array of arrays. Therefore, you must spread both of them.

I hope it's clearer now. If you have any more questions, please feel free to ask.

Comment: Yes your solution worked. Can you please explain a bit more why we had to use spread operator with the map function? Didn't get the logic well

Comment: Of course! I've edited my main post with a more detailed explanation, since I can't really format in comments.